# Lie derivative of surface gravity on killing horizon

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields

Carroll's 'spacetime and geometry' says surface gravity $\kappa$ is defined by $K^\mu \nabla_\mu K=-\kappa K$ where $\nabla$ and $K$ each denote covariant derivative and Killing vector field.
This is my question; $\mathscr{L}_K (\kappa)=0$, Lie derivative of $\kappa$ along $K$ is zero. 
My approach was using Leibniz rule $\mathscr{L}_K (\kappa K)=\kappa \mathscr{L}_K (K)+K\mathscr{L}_K (\kappa)$ then show that $\mathscr{L}_K (\kappa K)=-\mathscr{L}_K (K^\mu \nabla_\mu K)=0$ while $\mathscr{L}_K (K)=0$ trivially. But it didn't work well. Do anybody have some ideas on it?

Comment: Perhaps you have forgotten to consider that the definition of surface gravity is valid on a Killing horizon where $K^a K_a = 0$